# Android Firebase OAuth sign in strange behavior

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication, facebook-sdk-4.x

When I first time sign in with Google Account, then log in using Facebook account Firbase return **"ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL"**
 It's correct because I disabled sign multi credential options from firebase console.

The problem occurs when I first log in using the Facebook account.
The providers is correct, and UserInfo is shows facebook user account info. But email is not verified.

```
FirebaseUser user = getFirebaseUser();
user.isEmailVerified() // is false
```

And very strange behavior occurs when I sign in Google account.
The fist firebase does not return the same credential exception.Because I have login by facebook account. And Firebase removed facebook account, but i have login in by facebook account.
Facbook user info removed from `user.getProviderData()`
I have check Firebase console. There displayed that I logid in by Facebook

Answer (score 1):

Check this post to understand why Facebook emails are not verified: [Firebase Facebook auth: email verified always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398545/firebase-facebook-auth-email-verified-always-false)

If you want to consider Facebook emails verified, you can use the Admin SDK `admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {emailVerified: true})` to set Facebook emails as verified. Learn more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Check this post for why the Facebook account gets unlinked after Google sign in: [Authentication using Facebook at first and then Google causes an error in Firebase for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947944/authentication-using-facebook-at-first-and-then-google-causes-an-error-in-fireba)